# Why does the same Windows 7 system DLL have different checksums?

Tags: windows-7

I use *Windows 7 Professional Edition x64*.

When I take the checksum of a system DLL, such as `%windir%\System32\shell32.dll`, it will differ from the checksum of a copy of that file - that is, taking this file and making a copy of it to another folder. Why?

Additional information: according to `sfc /scannow`, my file `DxpTaskSync.dll` is corrupted. Therefore I replaced it with the original version from the Windows 7 installation CD. Whenever I copy the original version back and forth between the `%windir%\System32\` folder and some other folder, the checksum changes back and forth. For taking the checksum, I use *RapidCRC*. Despite replacing `DxpTaskSync.dll` with the original version, `sfc /scannow` still reports corruption.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  What are you using to calculate the checksum?

Comment: @Ramhound, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have different patch / update levels. When you install an update from Windows Update the new file has a different hash. So make sure both files have the same file version.

Comment: My allegedly corrupted file `DxpTaskSync.dll` has the exact version as the original `DxpTaskSync.dll` file from the Windows 7 installation DVD (DLL version: `6.1.7601.17514`). When I place the DVD-version file into `%windir%\System32\`, the CRC changes. When I take a copy from that place, the copy's checksum is back to the DVD-version checksum.

Comment: maybe you've copied the 32Bit version or your tool is 32Bit and uses the 32Bit Dll from syswow64 folder?

Comment: Taking a look at the `SysWOW64` folder: A DLL's checksum doesn't change when being copied from there. And the `SysWOW64` DLL has the same checksum as the DLL in the `System32` folder...

Answer (score 1):

When I spoke with a Windows Tech about refreshing certain DLL files in my system to correct problems, he explained that many of these files are dynamic not only from one system to another but even within the same system depending on the state its in, which programs are installed, etc.  It's ALIVE!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using 32 bit tool to create MD5 checksum Windows OS will redirect you (transparently) to `%windir%\sysWOW64` folder. This WOW effect is described in a [white paper](http://cert.at/downloads/papers/wow_effect_en.html).

You can also search for File System Redirector on MSDN sites.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Also note that the default version of fciv.exe from Microsoft is 32 bit.